# Stopping supervisor process without killing other child processes

Tags: supervisord

I am using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage my worker nodes in [gearman](http://gearman.org/). The config file looks like this

```
[program:public_pdf_convert]
process_name = pdf_convert_%(process_num)02d
command = /usr/local/bin/php worker_pdf_convert.php
numprocs = 2
directory = /projects/mv2/deliver/batch/batch/workers/
stopsignal = INT

[program:public_video_convert]
process_name = video_convert_%(process_num)02d
command = /usr/local/bin/php worker_video_convert.php
numprocs = 4
directory = /projects/mv2/deliver/batch/batch/workers/
stopsignal = INT
```

When I start supervisor, both the worker types (public_video_convert) and (public_pdf_convert) start 4 and 2 processes respectively.

Now I want to stop supervisor, without killing these six processes. I tried different `stopsignal` values with no luck. Basically, I want to the busy processes o continue to run and qui when they are finished. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle signals directly in your php worker. Supervisord will send the specified `stopsignal` (`TERM` by default) and wait `stopwaitsecs` before killing it.

To achieve that, I do this in my workers :

```
class Worker
{
    protected $shouldStop = false;

    public function stop()
    {
        $this->shouldStop = true;
    }

    protected function main()
    {
        // You handle both SIGINT and SIGTERM and add stop method as a callback
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [$this, 'stop']);
        pcntl_signal(SIGINT, [$this, 'stop']);

        while (true) {

            // Calls signal handlers for pending signals
            pcntl_signal_dispatch();

            if (true === $this->shouldStop) {
                // handler was called
                break;
            }

            // Do your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this, but I can't get the `pcntl_signal` callbacks to work. I posted a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979253/pcntl-signal-callbacks-are-not-executed) for it.