# pcntl_signal callbacks are not executed

Tags: php, supervisord, gearman

I am using php 5.4. I am using gearman and supervisor to control gearman workers. I want to catch the `TERM` signal produced by supervisor in PHP. I have the following worker code:

```
    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function($sig){
       error_log("interrupted", false);
    });

    while(true){
        pcntl_signal_dispatch();
            $gw->work();
        }
    }
```

My supervisor conf file is as follows:

```
[program:public_pdf_convert]
process_name = pdf_convert_%(process_num)02d
command = /usr/local/bin/php worker_pdf_convert.php
numprocs = 1
directory = /projects/mv2/deliver/batch/batch/workers/
```

By default, supervisor use `TERM`. When I stop supervisor, I can check that the gearman worker keeps running, but the callback for `pcntl_signal` is never called. I have tried with `INT` signal also.

Comment: I know this is over 2 years old, but I'm now in the same boat.  I can run the scripts manually and it'll catch the signals no problem.  When they're ran via supervisord, the signals don't make it through.  I've even added the 'stopsignal=TERM' to the supervisord conf files and still no luck.